# Have you implemented commenting features?

Tags: discussion

We're researching the idea of *commenting* on SDL Web (Tridion) items. Two of the questions we have are:

- "Do we know of clients who have done similar things?"
- "Is there a limitation to the size of the field?"

I know the community (@ChrisSummers) created the [Item Commenting Tool](https://github.com/TridionCommunity/tridion-powertools/blob/wiki/ItemCommenting.md) and @NickRousakov suggested an extension for *per-field* commenting at the last Tridion Developer Summit.

**Have you implemented some type of commenting in your projects and how did it work out with your client(s)?**

Answer (score 2):

'Back in the day' (Tridion 5.2) I had a client that had version commenting (on a component) just in a metadata field.

Obviously that isn't so interesting, but there was also an additional field to flag whether the update needed to be reflected (i.e. translated) in the child content publications. For example, a typo in the English version would not need to be translated, but adding a new paragraph to the content would. They then had additional (Event System) code to flag this (via email) to the country editors.

Scope creep! :)

Comment: Haha, yes on the scope creep. Though I'd expect the same that you start with a comment and work towards more collaborative features. At the far end you get a request for something like "simultaneous editing," but let's start with seeing if comments would be a useful.

Answer (score 1):

We commonly comment our work in Tridion. Usually this is either directly in code, for things like XSLT templates, where there will be a header with version information. Code components have a dedicated field for comments, and various other things could do with comments but there's no obvious place for them.

Being able to put a "commit message" on a version would go a long way to help.